# Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\emraan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-cli\bin\vue'

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-4

when checking the vue version or creating a new vue project. I got error

```
emraan> vue --version
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\emraan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-cli\bin\vue'
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: Reinstall the Vue CLI `npm i -g @vue/cli`

Comment: done 3 times but failed

Comment: got error 
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\emraan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\bin\vue.js
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\emraan\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.ps1
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\emraan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\bin\vue.js' -> 'C:\Users\emraan\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.ps1'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\emraan\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.ps1
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

Comment: Try uninstalling it first ~ `npm uninstall -g @vue/cli`

Comment: this is the first time I'm getting up-to date message

PS d:\ELECTRON> npm uninstall -g @vue/cli
up to date in 0.04s